# Converting JSONArray to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, rest

I am writing a rest java service. I want to convert my JSONArray to JSONObject and return it. But I am getting "{}" as output when I hit my rest service from browser. Although it is printing fine inside rest service when i tried to print using System.out.println();

```
PreparedStatement dimDelPS = null;
ResultSet dimDelRS = null;
dimDelPS = connection.prepareStatement("select * from abc");
dimDelRS = dimDelPS.executeQuery();
String dimLow=null;

while (dimDelRS.next()) {
    int total_rows = dimDelRS.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < total_rows; i++) {
        org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject();
        obj.put(dimDelRS.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i + 1)
                .toLowerCase(), dimDelRS.getObject(i + 1));
        jsonArray.put(obj);
    }
}

System.out.println("json1 :"+jsonArray);

//Sample output at this stage: ["{\"employee\":\"ANTHONY.DUNNE\"}","{\"type\":\"Manager\"}"]

dimDelRS.close();
dimDelPS.close();
JSONObject jsobobject= new JSONObject();
jsobobject.put("aoColumnDefs",jsonArray);
System.out.println(jsobobject);
return jsobobject;
```

Comment: No, Its not working, the browser is displaying {}

Comment: You have not provided enough information. As far as we can tell, the above code snippet has nothing to do with a browser or a REST call. Are you using a framework? What does the whole method look like? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, who upvoted this question? It is terrible.

Comment: I think the problem is with the json. Your json should be like

{ "aoColumnDefs" : [ { "employee": "ANTHONY.DUNNE" }, { "type":"Manager" } ] }

Answer (score 1):

You can't just return JSONObject.

You need to male sure you Marshall it into json.

'return Response.ok(jsonObject.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();'

Browser understand String, and not java object.

Comment: Please bear with my bad format, answering from mobile.

Comment: This makes a rather large assumption that OP is using JAX-RS. There is no evidence in the question to support this.

Comment: Its not working. I just replace the return type to Response and the last line with what you provided. Still its {} on browser.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked. 
 return Response.ok(jsobobject.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

Comment: Bravo, can you also update/edit answer and also format if possible :P

Comment: I just added replaced jsonObject with jsonObject.toString() in your answer